# Ubuntu won't boot after moving HD to HD caddy (laptop's DVD slot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

I've moved HD with Ubuntu v18 to HD caddy (DVD slot) and in place of that HD inserted a new SSD and installed Ubuntu v20. Everything works, but I cannot boot into old Ubuntu v18 despite having such option in the GRUB menu.

I tried fixing it by boot-repair but it doesn't help.

Selecting option Ubuntu v18 returns:

```
error: no such device: [drive id here]
error: hd1 cannot get C/H/S values.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

My drive setup provided by boot-repair
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B9rW6bxWXM/

**Strangely enough it does work if I press F12 during the boot, manually confirm "Hard Drive" selection and THEN select Ubuntu v18.**

Comment: Not sure I then understand as grub in sdb's MBR (caddy) loads grub in SSD to start boot. Is that when entry in SSD's grub works?  We have seen where systems with DVD caddy will not directly boot, even though DVDs boot. They often then have grub and maybe /boot on internal drive & rest of install on partitions on drive in caddy.

Comment: Based on your F12 experience then maybe you can set the "Hard Drive" in the Bios to be bootable or a boot entry.  Then when grub loads it may load/mount that as well. At least you do have a way to get in.

Comment: @walttheboss I think Hard Drive option is where my SSD is at, not where the old faulty HD drive in caddy is. Both optical drive (DVD) and HD are bootable in BIOS. But going through that boot choice selection seems to mount the HD drive in caddy, so inability to automatically mount HD in caddy seems to be root cause. I've set sdb1 (HD) to mount on Ubuntu startup, but it's not good enough, I need to know how to mount it also on boot.